# Is the Bede BD5 actually a tandem wing airplane, and not a mono wing?

Tags: aerodynamics

Is the Bede BD5 a tandem wing airplane, and not a mono wing?

The following picture (Source: Wikipedia.org) shows a Bede BD5 with a high angle of incidence on the horizontal tail, estimated at about 5 deg.

Being a rear engined airplane ( estimated fuel and engine north of 150 lbs) and with the main wing close to the pilot(150 lbs+), it seems the CG would be aft of the main wing.

Does this mean the vertical tail was used to generate some of the total lift (estimated at about 30%),in straight and level flight, thus making the BD5 a tandem wing, and not a mono plane?

[image: BEDE BD5 Front Quarter Shot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The BD-5 uses a stabilator for the horizontal tail with a single wing. When parked and the gust locks are in place the stabilator is in the 'pitch down' position you see in the picture. As the whole surface moves, the apparent incidence is not present when in normal flight.

Comment: Why did Bede use a stabilator?  I assume it has something to do with the extremely short lever arm between the  tail and the cg?

Comment: I don't know why he did, but your assumption is a reasonable guess.